# Paxos questions: if proposer down, what happened?

Tags: distributed-transactions, distributed-system

I'm going through kinds of scenarios which the basic Paxos algorithm could get agreement of final result. There's one case I can't explain the result.

There's two proposed P1 P2, three acceptor A1 A2 A3. P1 would propose value u, P2 would propose value v.

**1.** P1(send id n) finish the prepare step, receive all promise from A1 A2 A3, then in A1 A2 A3 all store n as id.

**2.** P2(send id n+1) then A1 A2 A3 store n+1 as id

**3.** P2 down.

**4.** P1 send accept request with (n, u) to A1 A2 A3, of course A1 A2 A3 would refuse the request, unfortunately at the same time P2 already down.

Such proposer down case, what would we do next? another new round of Paxos?

Comment: can you provide a bit of context here? why do you need P2 to be online if the quorum(A1,A2,A3) already accepted the value proposed by P2?

Comment: A1, A2, A3 just reply OK to P2 in prepare stage and store id in there local storage. Before P2 send the accept request with the value v, P2 is down. Which means the value haven't decided by (A1, A2, A3), because v is not arrived. But P1(id is n) send any accept request would be dropped by A1,A2,A3, because it's id is smaller than P2's id (n+1).

Answer (score 1):

Do a new paxos round, this is exactly what it is for.

The proposers send their value in the Prepare message, so the acceptors will send P2's value to P1 in the next paxos round.

Comment: hey, Micheal, as you said "do a new Paxos round", if not get the consistent result, it that means a Paxos round finished?

Comment: @TongxuanLiu A proposer can quit when it receives an Accept-Ack from a simple majority of acceptors. Before then, it doesn't know if a value is committed.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed all my notes and material from class when I studied this a few years ago. And for a Paxos correct implementation, it must be fault tolerant and never terminate, in both side, proposers and acceptors. Since the question is about fault tolerance for proposers, i'll focus on them:

A solution (but not the only one) to this issue, is to replicate the proposers, having several instances of each proposer type, one of them being the leader/master choosen at the begining, and is the one who sends the proposals.  If the master fails, another one, whom might be decided in a new election, or use a priority stablished on the initialization, steps up as new master, and take its place.

In this case you could have 3 instances of P2: P2-1, P2-2, P2-3 with P2-1 being the leader by default, if P2-1 fails, then P2-2 can step up.

Have to keep in mind, that the acceptors can ask for acknowledgement of P2 and P2-2 is still in the middle of stepping up as new leader, so probably is a good idea to set a retry after a timeout, to give P2-2 enough time to be ready.

Comment: It's a way to void the issue. To keep the liveness of the system, replica and timeout is always the way.

Answer (score 0):

**"Paxos Made Simple" Lamport**

"*It’s easy to construct a scenario in which two proposers each keep issuing a sequence of proposals with increasing numbers, none of which are ever chosen. Proposer p completes phase 1 for a proposal number n1. Another proposer q then completes phase 1 for a proposal number n2 > n1. Proposer p’s phase 2 accept requests for a proposal numbered n1 are ignored because the acceptors have all promised not to accept any new proposal numbered less than n2. So, proposer p then begins and completes phase 1 for a new proposal number n3 > n2, causing the second phase 2 accept requests of proposer q to be ignored. And so on.*"

From the description Step 4: 
(A1,A2,A3) would reply the accept request from P1, send id+1 to P1, then P1 is notified and increase id -> id+2. P1 send to (A1,A2,A3) prepare request again with id+2. In order to avoid live-lock between P1 and P2, better way should be only one proposer (reference to 2.4 chapter of "Paxos Made Simple").

Comment: is a good point, although, this concern was not expressed on the first question, i'd add this to the original question, to enrich it more for those who might read it in the future.

Comment: certainly the paxos parliament protocol has a leader as per https://simbo1905.wordpress.com/2016/01/02/paxos-uses-leaders-multi-paxos-is-paxos/ but you need logic to ensure that when it crashes it is replaced by only one new proposer safely. that can be done with exponential back offs such that each node which fails to win a round waits for a longer time before retrying to be the leader as outlined at https://simbo1905.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/transaction-log-replication-with-paxos/